# Downgrade Debian to 4.4 kernel

Tags: debian, kernel

I have never experienced with doing anything with kernels so i need an advice how to do it. The reason why is to implement this:

https://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,143371.msg1225171.html?PHPSESSID=feu49cfn3vvi6qpjqbh8e4mht3#msg1225171

because I have the same issue with Toshiba Satellite A300-1eb laptop as in this thread.

Should I do the downgrade in Debian Buster or Stretch? How to to the downgrade to 4.4 kernel?

Comment: Are you sure a solution from 2017 is adequate? Would you also stick to 2017 software?

Comment: @A.B I could not find any othe solution. One advice was to disable ACPI in bios, but there was not that option in the bios.

Comment: So like in the link, your only problem is a message written at boot? That's the issue?

Comment: No. A boot time is 5 minutes.

Comment: Please have a look there: https://xyproblem.info/ (and there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). That's your current issue. You should think about it and rewrite the question.

Comment: If during those 5mn you see only the ACPI message, that doesn't mean at all that the ACPI message causes the 5mn delay. Your link tells "Following installation, everything seems to run very smoothly, except for an error message which shows, each time the machine is booted up". There is no other issue in this link.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. So I will prepare another question with the long boot time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through `apt`, the Linux kernel `4.4` can be installed on Debian Jessie using the backported version from [snapshot](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux-latest/71%7Ebpo8%2B1/#linux-image-amd64_4.4:2b:71:7e:bpo8:2b:1).

On Debian Buster you need to compile the `4.4*` kernel. Here is some documentation:

nixcraft: [How to compile and install Linux Kernel 5.6.9 from source code](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html)

Kernel handbook: [Chapter 4. Common kernel-related tasks](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html)

[Link to Linux kernel source V4.x](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/)